# Calculate the 5-day moving average - Set value to 0 if there is a gap between dates.

Tags: php, mysql, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate the 5-day moving average. And everything works fine, except when there is a gap between dates. When there is a gap, the value for the missing date(-s) should be set to zero to show the correct moving average.

Here is my table (orders_total) and you can see that there is no date for 1/7/13 and that is causing the problem:

```
orders_id    value    date
1            199      1/1/13 0:00
2            199      1/2/13 0:00
3            199      1/3/13 0:00
4            199      1/4/13 0:00
5            249      1/5/13 0:00
6            199      1/6/13 0:00
7            199      1/8/13 0:00
8            199      1/9/13 0:00
9            199      1/10/13 0:00
10           199      1/11/13 0:00
11           199      1/12/13 0:00
12           199      1/13/13 0:00
```

If the value for missing date 1/7/13 is set to zero, the correct 5-day moving average (that 'm looking for) is:

```
199
199
199
199
209
209
169.2
169.2
169.2
159.2
159.2
199
199
```

This is the code I'm using, and it is not showing the correct moving average when there is a gap between dates:

```
    SELECT ot1.value, ot1.date,
    (SELECT SUM(ot2.value) / COUNT(ot2.value)
    FROM orders_total AS ot2 WHERE DATEDIFF(ot1.date, ot2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4) AS '5dayMovingAvg'
    FROM orders_total AS ot1 ORDER BY ot1.date";
```

Comment: Consider constructing a calendar utility table holding all dates, and then join your tables onto that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that it will always be 5 days, why divide by COUNT(ot2.value)?  Unless you're trying to handle edge cases, in which case, handle the edge cases differently than the normal case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ot1.value, ot1.date,
            (    SELECT SUM(ot2.value) / COUNT(ot2.value)
            FROM (

     select * from orders_total union
        (SELECT 0 as order_id,0 as `value`,DATE(r1.date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS missing_date
        FROM orders_total r1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_total r2 ON DATE(r1.date) = DATE(r2.date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        WHERE r2.date IS NULL )

) AS ot2 WHERE DATEDIFF(ot1.date, ot2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4) AS '5dayMovingAvg'
            FROM (

    select * from orders_total union
        (SELECT 0 as order_id,0 as `value`,DATE(r1.date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS missing_date
        FROM orders_total r1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_total r2 ON DATE(r1.date) = DATE(r2.date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        WHERE r2.date IS NULL )

) 

        AS ot1 ORDER BY ot1.date
```

Basically what I have done is I have replaced orders_total tabel from your query and replaced with

```
select * from orders_total union
        (SELECT 0 as order_id,0 as `value`,DATE(r1.date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS missing_date
        FROM orders_total r1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_total r2 ON DATE(r1.date) = DATE(r2.date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        WHERE r2.date IS NULL )
```

this query , I could have placed it in view but mysql view doesn't support union in view probably a bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9198

note:this will also include one extra row for date you can exclude it with max(date)

result from above query:

```
199 2013-01-01 00:00:00 199.0000
199 2013-01-02 00:00:00 199.0000
199 2013-01-03 00:00:00 199.0000
199 2013-01-04 00:00:00 199.0000
249 2013-01-05 00:00:00 209.0000
199 2013-01-06 00:00:00 209.0000
0   2013-01-07 00:00:00 169.2000
199 2013-01-08 00:00:00 169.2000
199 2013-01-09 00:00:00 169.2000
199 2013-01-10 00:00:00 159.2000
199 2013-01-11 00:00:00 159.2000
199 2013-01-12 00:00:00 199.0000
199 2013-01-13 00:00:00 199.0000
0   2013-01-14 00:00:00 159.2000
```

Comment: Thanks! But, when trying your query I received error message:

1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: what is your `orders_total` table's schema??

Comment: replace this `select * from orders_total union` with this `select order_id,value,date from orders_total union` in query and then try. Hope this helps.